# Remove Meta Ray-Ban add on Instagram Post

Tags: ios, exif, instagram

Is there a quick way to remove the note on my instagram posts that shows that the photo was created using Ray-Ban meta?

[image: Photo that shows an Instagram post with a note "Mit Ray-Ban | Meta erstellt" right below the user name]

The photo shows "Mit Ray-Ban | Meta erstellt" which is German for "Created with Ray-Ban | Meta"

Is there a setting in Instagram that disables showing this note?

I assume, I can remove all the meta-information from the photo, or more specifically "Make" and "Model" from the EXIF date. Is there a quick way on iOS to do this? I tried a few things, but it seems I can only remove date/time and location information

Comment: A google for "ios edit photo metadata" seems to give several options.